# template inheritance from multiple sub-templates

Tags: javascript, node.js, swig-template

So i have a website, it's structure is consisted of various templates:

```
- index //the html skeleton, with script tags and css links
- header //the header of the page
- topnavigation //contains the main nav with the menu
- content //this is where the dynamic content will be changed for different pages
- footer //the footer
```

Right now, the only way i know to integrate this is:

```
res.render(content);    
content -> inherits footer
footer -> inherits topnavigation
topnavigation-> inherits header
header -> inherits index
```

I think it would be much more practical and easy to maintain if i could have something like:

```
res.render(content);
content -> inherits dochead
index -> includes header + topnnavigation + footer
```

- Am I wrong?
- If i'm right, how can i do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typical `extends` setup is something more like this: (for a working example, you can see how the Swig documentation sets up its layouts here: https://github.com/paularmstrong/swig/tree/master/docs/layouts)

- `skeleton.html` html skeleton with blocks:

  - `{% block html %}`
  - `{% block css %}`
  - `{% block js %}`
  - `{% block body %}`
- `base.html` extends `skeleton.html`, base layout with blocks/sub-blocks:

  - `{% block body %}`

    - `{% block header %}` Includes some default header content.

      - `{% block nav %}` Includes the main navigation content.
    - `{% block content %}` Empty
    - `{% block footer %}` Includes copyright, etc.
- `index.html` extends `base.html`

  - `{% block nav %}` (content for navigation, potentially, otherwise just let `base.html` render its nav content
  - You'll override any other blocks set up in `base.html` here as needed as well. If you find yourself needing more control over the template, consider creating another sub-layout that extends `base.html` and then having `index.html` extend that instead.

Comment: how do you deal with sub-directories?

Comment: How would you do this but put all of the content templating in its own file? Normally I would use an include but this breaks the extends/block inheritance. I'd much rather keep the distinct components of my page in their own files because it gets unwieldily otherwise. I have something like 3 or 4 different major content blocks (and it could grow further in the future).